# Selecting the 1st and then subsequent elements in an expression

Tags: expression-manipulation, arguments

I'm using a mixture of `Span` and `Part` to try and extract the arguments of a function that I need.

I'm using a function such as $J^\mu(1,2,3)$
and I'll be trying to represent this as `J[mu,Range[1,3]]`or more generally for any index or any number of arguments, `J[index_,Range[1,n_]]`.

I'll need to select the first element, i.e the index of this function every time, and then I'll need to select a few consecutive elements of the list. I.e; I'll need to select terms such as `J[index,2,3]`.

I've tried using some variations of `Span` inside the `Part`argument, but I'm struggling to solely take the first variable, plus some extras.

Particularly, I'm trying to program the Berends-Giele recursion relation for n-gluons.

Any help would be much appreciated.

#### Edit

To show an example:

```
J[mu,1,2,3,4,5][[3;;5]]
```

gives a result of

> ```
> J[2,3,4]
> ```

as expected. When I take

```
J[mu,1,2,3,4,5][[1]]
```

I get

> ```
> mu
> ```

which is not expected.

What I'd like is something like

```
J[mu,1,2,3,4,5][[1,3;;4]]
```

and get

> ```
> J[mu,3,4]
> ```

Is that possible using `Span` and `Part`?

Comment: Is `J[mu, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5][[{1, 4, 5}]]` acceptable?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much! If I can accept that as an answer to help you then I'll happily do so. I don't know why I didn't try that first correctly. Much appreciate Kuba.

Comment: Since this is part of `ref / Part / Generalizations and extensions` let me know as mark it as easy to find in documentation. Don't get me wrong, I know it is easy to miss things in such a big system but still, it is there in a place that is somewhat expected to address it.